# On the nature of goods?

Tags: utilitarianism

If I have an apple and you have an apple and we both exchange we both still have one apple. But if I have an idea and you have an idea and we both exchange we have 2 ideas.

Obviously the exchange of information is different from exchange of apples.

For apples we have supply demand curves. Does utilitarianism not get challenged by the assumption all goods can be tied to a currency? How do economists handle this?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149514/discussion-on-question-by-more-anonymous-on-the-nature-of-goods); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.